# Switching views crashes app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

This is a very odd problem.

I include the .h file of the next view:

```
#import "MainGame.h"
```

The I have this code to switch rooms when I press the screen:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    MainGame *newview = [[MainGame alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainGame" bundle:nil];
    newview.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:newview animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

And it works fine in the iOS 5 simulator; but when I test it on my iPod running iOS 4.2 it always just crashes.

All my IBOutlets are connected correctly and everything, as I've already said it works fine in the simulator but not on my iPod.

I have had each individual view working on my iPod before, so I am not using any features which require iOS 5 or anything; it's just this code that switches views that is not working.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the error log on the question?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the [[MainGame alloc] initWithNibName:..] issue?

Comment: If I remove the line: [self presentViewController:newview animated:YES completion:NULL]; then the app no longer crashes so I'm pretty sure that this line is what's causing the issue. Also do I can't error log it because debugging doesn't work on my iPod.

Comment: What about `MainGame`'s `viewDidLoad`? And why do you think debugging is not working? You can debug step-by-step on your device exactly the same like it's Simulator.

Comment: viewDidLoad for MainGame just says:

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

My init code is in:

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe its a version issue

```
[self presentViewController:newview animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

doesn't exist in iOS 4.2 but does in iOS 5

try this instead

```
[self presentModalViewController:newview animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the Apple documentation, presentViewController is iOS 5.0 and above.

Comment: I already have the answer but thanks anyway; I've marked your answer as helpful.